# How to use a variable as the seed to an identity column while creating tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-column

I want to put the set the seed of the identity column of a table based on some variable.

For eg. something like that.

```
DECLARE @seed INT
SELECT @seed = MAX(id) 
  FROM tblSomeTable
```

Now, using @seed, I want to seed of my new table.

For eg. something like this:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
  ID INT IDENTITY(@seed,1) PRIMARY KEY, DESC NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

This actually throws an error saying incorrect syntax. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fully dynamic SQL and embed the seed value in the string containing the `CREATE TABLE` statement (or `DECLARE ... TABLE` statement).  Most DDL statements do not allow variables in them.